# Text is not displayed in the window using tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()
display = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...") #this is displayed
display.pack()
frame.pack()
display.update()

def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.pack()
    frame.pack()


change_root_label("Opening...") #this is not been displayed
print("hello") #though this is printed
time.sleep(15)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
change_root_label("Opened...") #this is also displayed


root.mainloop()
```

I added "time.sleep(15)" for testing if it takes time to display..., but then also it was not displayed...

Comment: No need `wait` after opening google the text will display. Try without the delay.

Comment: `time.sleep()` prevents ANYTHING from happening for the duration (in the same thread, at least) - including the updating of your GUI.

Comment: If I remove `time.sleep`, then also it is not executing `change_root_label("Opening...")` which is before wait and before opening browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to update the GUI. Use `root.update()`. Also I will not suggest you to use the delay as it will pause the whole script and will prevent selenium from opening webdiver for 15 sec.

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()
display = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...") #this is displayed
display.pack()
frame.pack()
display.update()

def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.pack()
    frame.pack()


change_root_label("Opening...") #this is not been displayed
print("hello") #though this is printed
root.update()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
change_root_label("Opened...") #this is also displayed


root.mainloop()
```

If you want a more simple way then just edit your function:

```
def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.pack()
    frame.pack()
    root.update()
```

Comment: I went with edit in function, can I know why `data;` tab is opened, every time I open webdriver? [See Image](https://imgur.com/5jDygDd) for more clarification..

Comment: @Slook Well , I don't have much knowledge about `selenium`. As far as I have tested, it don't happens with me. You can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this. And it will work. 
You need to update the widget everytime you change its text via this process.

```
def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.pack()
    frame.pack()
    label.update()
```